# Ubuntu Software update check size is unreasonably large

Tags: update-manager

When I check for updates, I see that it is using my internet at full capacity (128Kb/s) for about 3 minutes. That is something like 25MB of data downloaded -- just to know if there are updates for my computer. After that, I still get a window showing me that I can now download those new updates for another 20+MB's!

Do I have something wrong in my settings, or is this normal?

Comment: What *exactly* are you asking?

Comment: @UriHerrera This has been [quite reasonably answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/249176/22949), so there is probably no longer any reason to close it.

Comment: Very accurate edit @belacqua

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question was why is it that updating your Software Sources used 25mb's of data? That is too much, it is only reading text from the sources, and you are right about that. The answer is that it did not use 25mb! The fact is that although the download speed is 128kb/s, it does not mean that it is ***constantly downloading data***. Most of the time it is simply processing. As a test, open your Terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Enter your password when asked, and wait for it to finish downloading the sources. You can clearly see in the Terminal the exact amount of data downloaded. On my laptop, with many packages added to the default set, you can see that it only took 1,235kb (1.2mb).
During the download it said it was downloading at 137kb/s, once it was complete you can see the average speed was 13.3 kb/s.

[image: High lighted text, 1,235 kb]

This is the equivalent of the "window with a progress bar moving right and left while checking if there are any updates for my computer."